# Individual view from an item in an ArrayController

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have an ember.js model and controller setup like so:

```
//model
App.Order = Ember.Object.extend({

  content: null,

  create: function(data) {
    this.set('content', data);
    return this._super();
  }

});

//orders controller
App.ordersController = Ember.ArrayController.create({

  content: [],

  init: function() {

        var self = this;
    var orders = [];

    $.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data) {  
        data.forEach(function(item) { 
          var order = App.Order.create(item);
          orders.push(order);
        });
      self.set('content', orders);
    });
    },

  selectItem: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }

});
```

With the following view:

```
{{#each App.ordersController}} 
   <div {{action selectItem target="App.ordersController"}}>{{order_number}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Which prints out a list of orders with a click action that alerts the corresponding item. This works fine.

What I want to do is show a clicked item in a separate view, eventually with the goal of creating a floating dialogue with orders details shown. I'm new to ember and not sure how this should be implemented. I have a function `selectItem` which alert's a clicked order but I need to link this to a separate view and print the order details.

Should I store the selected item in a separate controller with a corresponding view and update this when `selectItem` is clicked? Or could I update a sperate view from the ordersController? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the router. That is made especially for these situations. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/

Comment: Is my answer clear to you? Should I elaborate on anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the router ember does the instantiation of your class for you. By specifing the `"orders"` route is looks for a template called `orders` and a controller called `OrdersController` if it can't find one it'll generate one for you. (I've omitted the controller for clearity). To load your model from a json source you could have a look at ember-data.

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVeXx/3/) so you can fiddle with it a bit.

You should definitely have a look [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/) these are guides for ember that really help you on the way. The documentation is getting better and better. :)

**JS:**

```
window.App = App = Em.Application.create();

//model
App.Order = Ember.Object.extend({
    order_number: null,
});


//we create 2 routes one for all the order and one per specific order
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('orders', { path: "/" });
    this.resource("order", { path: "/:order_id" });    
});

//the route supplies the model and handles the event to transition to a new route.    
App.OrdersRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    events: {
        selectItem: function (orderId) {
            //select the order by the "orderId" you want as a model for your new view.
            this.transitionTo("order", order);
        }
    },
    model: function(){
        return content; //an array containing the orders;
    }
});

//supplies the model for the "order" route by selecting one acording to the params;
App.OrderRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return order; //select an object from the array according to the params
    },    
});
```

**HBS:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="orders">
    {{#each controller}} 
      <!-- this calls the event handler "selectItem" on the ordersroute -->
      <div {{action "selectItem" order_number}}>{{order_number}}</div>
    {{/each}}

    <!-- this is handled by "App.OrderRoute" -->
    <a href="#/3"/>with a direct link</a>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="order">
    {{content.order_number}}
    {{#linkTo "orders"}}Back to orders{{/linkTo}}
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed response. Routes are the way to go.